# Saving data to file in Red language

Tags: file, fwrite, rebol, red

I am trying to save data to a file:

```
a: 0
b: 10
c: 20
d: 30

save %redout.txt [a b c d]
```

I expected the file to contain the values. However, The file contains:

```
a b c d
```

How can I save variable values rather than variable names to the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're saving a block which hasn't been evaluated. Normally you would reduce the block first to get the values before saving them.

So,

```
 Save %myfile.txt reduce [a b c d]
```

And if you want a loadable file with variables, use `save/all`

Comment: This page mentions that `save/all - not available yet` : http://www.red-by-example.org/index.html#save . I tried but only values are saved as by simple save.

Comment: But it&amp;#39;s available in rebol, and rebol3. And it's just a matter of time for red

Comment: @rnso I strongly recommend saving with a header as well. It's a good way to add metadata to your data blocks. (look up `SAVE/HEADER`)